# Windows 7 sharing issues

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, file-sharing, homegroup

I have two desktops with Windows 7 Pro 32 bit, one laptop with Windows 7 Pro 64 bit and one netbook with Windows 7 Starter.  The two desktops can see each other.  From DT1 I can see and Read and Write on DT2.  From DT2 I can Read but not write on DT1.  Both are on a Workgroup and Homegroup.  Neither have the Password enabled for LAN.  On both I have given Everyone all rights.

Neither of the laptops appear in the Network area of Explorer on the desktops.  I can ping the laptops from DT1 but cannot ping DT1 from the laptops even though they are on the network and can get to the Internet through the router.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

With all the computers with full permissions, this sounds like it shouldn't be happening. You might want to try looking at the HomeGroup FAQ, if you haven't already: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/HomeGroup-frequently-asked-questions